# Inserting table in SQL server using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import

I am trying to import an excel file to SQL , the file has 3 columns : Box - Code - Validity
i am using the following query

```
USE [Libatel]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataExcel]

as

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select  Box, Code , Validity FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES',     'SELECT Box, Code , Validity FROM [sheet1$]')
declare @Code as bigint
declare @Box as bigint
declare @Validity as date

begin


open c 

fetch next from c into @Code,@Box,@Validity

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
select @Box = Box,@Code = BarCode,@Validity =ValidityDate from Cards 
Insert into Cards (BarCode,Box,ValidityDate) values (@Box,@Code,@Validity)
fetch next from c into @Box,@Code,@Validity
end
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c


end
```

I am getting the folowing

```
11155232026    1        2013-05-18  

1       11155232026     2013-05-18  


...
...
```

This is the first line always and Box and Code are changing places on each line , what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please dont use a cursor for this.  It's unnecessary.

Comment: Insert into dbo.MyTable (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnEtcEtc ) select  Box, Code , Validity FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES',     'SELECT Box, Code , Validity FROM [sheet1$]')

Comment: Or declare a @variable or #temp table and (set based) insert the rows from excel into it.  The cursor is unnecessary and a not-best-practice RBAR practice (row by agonizing row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `fetch` has the wrong column order:

```
fetch next from c into @Code,@Box,@Validity
...
fetch next from c into @Box,@Code,@Validity
```

Another problem is this statement:

```
select @Box = Box,@Code = BarCode,@Validity =ValidityDate from Cards
```

That effectively fetches a random row from the `Cards` table, discarding the values from the cursor.  Perhaps you could clarify what this line is supposed to do?

Comment: ok this worked fine thank you  , but i am still getting line 1 to appear in every line , any idea please ?

Comment: i am trying to read line by line the content of the excel file with the cursor and insert them in table "Cards:, everytime i use the "fetch: to access a new line , i don't know if i am making it right , the insert is working but line 1 of the excel file is being read only , and it is filled in all the row in the table "Cards"

Comment: Remove `select @Box = Box,@Code = BarCode,@Validity =ValidityDate from Cards` and see what happens :)

Comment: ok it worked now , had to remove the cursor to disable the loop

Comment: Please stop writing cursors when you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Holder table ( ColumnA varchar(24) , ColumnB varchar(32) , ColumnEtcEtc varchar(64))





Insert into @Holder (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnEtcEtc ) select Box, Code , Validity FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT Box, Code , Validity FROM [sheet1$]') 


Delete From @Holder where DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnB))) <=0
```

OR

```
Insert into @Holder (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnEtcEtc ) select Box, Code , Validity FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT Box, Code , Validity FROM [sheet1$] where ColumnA = 2 ')
```

I'm not an expert on where clauses with excel queries, but I'm guessing there is a way.